# convert sequence file to vector

Tags: mahout

I am trying to implement the naïve bayes algorithm to do sentiment analysis on tweet and facebook data in mahout. I have those tweets and facebook data in a text file. I am converting those files in to sequence file using the command

bin/mahout seqdirectory -i /user/hadoopUser/sample/input -o /user/hadoopUser/sample/seqoutput

and then I tried converting the sequence file in to vector, in order to give input to mahout using the command

bin/mahout seq2sparse -i /user/hadoopUser/sample/seqoutput -o /user/hadoopUser/vectoroutput -ow -a org.apache.lucene.analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer -chunk 200 -wt tfidf -s 5 -md 3 -x 90 -ng 2 -ml 50 -seq

This is converting the whole document in to vectors, but I want to convert each sentence in to vectors not as a whole because I don't want to classify the document. I want to classify the comments in the documents. Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you should have is a CSV file with tweets data right? I'm dealing with this exact same problem. What I did (I'm not sure if it worked as I don't even know how to interpret the clustering output, it's just a mess of numbers and words) I wrote each column of my CSV file into the sequence file using Mahout's SequenceWriter class. Then used seq2sparse like normal on that sequence file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but the main problem is that mahout sees this file like one key/value.
You need to add additional id, for example, md5 hash for each line.
So the CSV format will be:

```
positive    bf9373d6d85959ec755eb8ac5ba0ae77    This movie is a real masterpiece
```